# Does anyone know of a technology that allows one to edit the tags on pdfs?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am looking  to programmatically edit the tags in a pdf document.In particular I would like to be able to copy tags from one document to another, and edit them as I copy them over.

I have looked at coherent pdf, pythons pdfrw and pythons pdfedit and not been sucessful. I am creating the pdfs in Latex so any Latex based solution would be amazing, but i have not come up with anything that allows me to create tags).

Any advise?

Comment: With iText, you have access to the PDF at the lowest level. That is: you can programmatically change whatever is under the `/StructTreeRoot`. That means that you can also seriously damage a Tagged PDF if you make changes that are incorrect.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie do you know of any examples of people doing this? My first attempt used pdrwr to directly edit the structTreeRoot but I was never able to get this to work for adding a tag